# How to use underscore while formatting a string from Sitecore in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am getting two field values from an item in Sitecore. When I concatenate using string format, it's not showing the values. Instead, it shows only an underscore.

I have tried the following formats. None of them are working.

1. `"Name" = "{$record.FirstName}_{$record.LastName}";`
2. `"Name" = [string]::Format("{0}{1}",{$record.FirstName},{$LastName});`

Note: The values are coming fine from Sitecore. The issue is only with formatting.

Comment: Show us a minimal and relevant Powershell code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to either change to:

```
  $Name = "$($record.FirstName)_$($record.LastName)";
```

or to:

```
  $Name = "{0}_{1}" -f $record.FirstName, $record.LastName;
```

Hope that helps.